# Vue js не удалось загрузить изображения

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Начинаю осваивать vue.js.
Решил сделать Простое приложения для фильтрации данных
в папке src создал папку data в ней data.js

кусок кода:

```js
const data = [
 {
 name: 'vue js',
  //logo: '../assets/vue-logo.png',
 logo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Vue.png',
 stack: [ 'framework', 'frontend', 'web', 'mobile' ]
 },
  {
   name: 'react js',
   logo: './assets/react.png',
   stack: [ 'framework', 'frontend', 'web', 'mobile' ]
  },
 {
name: 'Slim Framework',
logo: '../assets/slim.png',
stack: [ 'backend','framework', 'web' ]
}
];
export default data;
```

я закачал картинки в папку **assets**

если прописываю путь картинки в таком формате

```
logo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Vue.png',
```

то картинка выводится

а если такой формат

```
logo: '../assets/vue-logo.png',
```

Не пойму почему не выводятся картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файлы проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просвятите

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас сервер смотрит в директорию бандла, допустим, `dist`, а ваша директория `assets` на уровни с `dist`, то так как браузер смотрит в `dist` и однозначно браузер не будет видеть `assets`.
Вам нужно поместить директорию `assets` в директорию с `dist` или при сборке копировать ее туда.
Если поместите `assets` с бандлом приложения вместе, то обращайтесь к картинкам `/assets` или `assets`